# Password storage for authentication

Tags: javascript, encryption, passwords

I'm trying to create basic password protection for a web page that doesn't have to be super secure, but I don't want to do something as simple as store the password in JS as someone with half a brain could view source.  (I work with engineers, so everyone who would use this has at least half a brain!)

Someone else suggested doing it through an AJAX call to a PHP script which stores the password.

Is this really any better?  Can't you view the network resources, ie using Chrome, and view the PHP file?

I tested the above using Chrome and did an inspect element and then under the 'Network' tab there was the file titled 'Passwords.txt' which i created...

I was thinking that I could store the passwords encoded only.  But i'd need something that only worked one way...  Ie you type in daveisawesome1234 and it encodes to something unintelligable like  OIWBOUQ#BP@#BR@FBNSAION.  This way if you see the 'Passwords.txt' file with `OIWBOUQ#BP@#BR@FBNSAION` in it you couldnt just type that in.  Problem with that is you'd just need to read the code to figure out how I encoded it...

Is there a simple method that will accomplish what I'm looking for?  I'm always learning, so please DO NOT suggest any libraries.  I want to learn to code this myself.

Thanks in advance,
Dave

EDIT:

Ok, I want to try something out.  I created a very basic page to test out 4 password 'encryption' methods.  Let me know if you figure out the passwords, and how you did it.

Here's the link: http://dck.dx.am/locktest/locktest.html

@Pointy: This should also illustrate what I was saying about being able to view the PHP file...

Please feel free to provide insights or offer up alternative methods.

Thanks, Dave

Comment: Unless you're doing something wrong, nobody can see your PHP sources from the internet.

Comment: Well, it appears that I'm doing something wrong, any idea what?  (i know it's vague, let me know what else you need to answer the question...)

Comment: If your PHP *source* can be read, then your server is misconfigured somehow. There are lots of possibilities.

Comment: If this doesn't have to be "super" secure, why does it have to be secure at all? If security is important to *anybody* involved, then your lack of experience with it seems like a problem (no offense intended).

Comment: No offence taken.  I want to learn.  Everyone has to start somewhere right!?

Comment: That's certainly true, and I of course encourage you to do so. I guess my point was that if there's any need for real security, you should probably enlist some help to at least review what you end up with.

Answer (score 1):

You can't view the PHP file from a browser unless the server is misconfigured. PHP is usually executed in the server, and the output is sent to the client. As long as the password isn't part of the output, it's relatively safe. That's the proper way to do it (the password shouldn't be embedded in the code, but it's not that bad if it's just for a quick-and-dirty project).

On the other hand, checking the password in the browser, no matter if it's "encoded", is never a good idea, as it would be pretty easy to bypass. Client-side security is no security.

As for "something that only worked one way", that's what [hashing algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashing_algorithm) are for.